# How can I change a Highcharts bar color based on a third field?

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I am trying to build a highcharts bar chart. I would like to change the colors of the bar depending on a third field. In [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/jmvzrLdf/) fiddle, you can change the color of the bar based on the y value. But how can I change this to change the color based on a z value? i.e.

```
{ x: 1
  y: 1.21
  z: "blue"
},
{ x: 2
  y: 1.13
  z: "green"
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `z` property for a data point, but you can use `color` property to control the color of a point using the "third field".

API references:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.color

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8mbqwa4r/